# What would be the username and password to use Oracle Enterprise Manager for the first time?

Tags: oracle11g

I have just successfully installed Oracle 11g. Now I have just reached the page:

[image]

What would be the username and password to use Oracle Service Manager 11g for the first time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you specify a default password during installation?

If yes try it with the `sys` username.

Comment: did you specify a default password during installation? If yes try it with the sys username